# Como puedo hacer una función con PHP para sacar datos de un file JSON?

Tags: php, json, script

Hola gente de stackoverflow soy nuevo y no se mucho de php tengo este problema, quiero sacar esa información pero no se cómo o con qué función se hace; quiero hacer una lista con esos datos `quality` , `url`.

Bueno espero que me puedan ayudar con mi problema y gracias por adelantado :)

linea del archivo **4700**:

```
 "USUV71800948.streamsV3.2": {
        "quality": "medium",
        "url": "http://mp4-video.vevo.com/v5/USUV71800948/mp4/c52c32a3-7eed-4c69-a7e0-6f8fbfd294ff/USUV71800948_med_640x360_h264_600_aac_128.mp4",
        "errorCode": null,
        "__typename": "StreamsV3"
    },
```

link del archivo JSON:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MLUL3g7MhoiEKjEwWGzdn5B4efyxRvkt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se entiende muy bien lo que pretendes, pero si quieres recuperar un json y usarlo desde PHP, se puede hacer así:

```
$objeto = json_decode($jon);
```

Y luego puedes acceder a los datos con:

```
echo $objeto->dato;
```

O puedes usarlo como array:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Y accederías así:

```
echo $array["dato"];
```

Ahora bien, si lo quieres a la inversa, es decir, partes de un array y quieres sacar un json, entonces harías:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Tienes la ayuda completa de json_decode en: http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php
Y la de json_encode en: http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php

Nota: Entiendo que tienes el json localmente en una variable, si no es así, a parte de que la pregunta deberías ser otra, podrías usar AJAX desde javascript para llamar el json o en PHP puedes usar CURL o cualquier otra función al respecto como file_get_contents tal como dice Diego Avila o como dice Levi Arista, aunque ya te digo que si es eso, tu pregunta no se entiende.

Comment: ya mire el post pero aun no puedo hacer qye funcione, quiero sacar eso datos me puedes ayudar si por favor

Comment: Deberías aportar tu código para que podamos ver dónde está el problema, de otra forma todo se vuelve muy complicado.

Comment: Por cierto, la forma más simple que conozco para recorrer un objeto/array sería primero haciendo un var_dump ya que ahí se indica si es objeto o array.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias obtener el contenido del JSON usando [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

**ejemplo:**

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://ejemplo.com/ejemplo.json/');
```

basados en eso para extrar un dato especifico puedes usar algo asi:

**mi json:**

```
"services":[
    {
        "id":101,
        "name":"Service 1 Name",
        "extras":[
            {
                "id":3,
                "name":"Extra Y",
            },
            {
                "id":8,
                "name":"Extra X",
            },
            {
                "id":12,
                "name":"Extra Z",
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

deseo extraer el **id 8** haria algo asi:

```
foreach ($services->services as $service) {
    if ($service->name == 'Service 1 Name') {
        foreach ($service->extras as $extra) {
            if ($extra->id == '8') {
                $id = $extra->id
                $name = $extra->name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

es una forma que podrias realizarlo .. suerte !!

Answer (score 0):

Para sacar data de arrays mutidimensionales, como en el caso de tu archivo,  puedes usar la función [RecursiveArrayIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/es/recursivearrayiterator.getchildren.php)

**Ejemplo de archivo:**

```
{
    "John": {
        "status":"Wait"
    },
    "Jennifer": {
        "status":"Active"
    },
    "James": {
        "status":"Active",
        "age":56,
        "count":10,
        "progress":0.0029857,
        "bad":0
    }
}
```

**Código:**

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
John:
status => Wait
Jennifer:
status => Active
James:
status => Active
age => 56
count => 10
progress => 0.0029857
bad => 0
```

---

*Respuesta tomada de esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/how-can-i-parse-a-json-file-with-php) de la comunidad en inglés*